# sql server - number results using two columns

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to number rows based on two columns - I can't quite articulate what I'm trying to do, so in this case I hope that the following tables will paint a thousand words.

Given the following table:

```
Name   | Car Colour
-------------------
 Alice | Red
 Alice | Green
 Alice | Blue
 Bill  | Orange
 Bill  | Purple
 Carol | Brown
 Carol | Orange
 Carol | Magenta
 Carol | Indigo
 Carol | Lilac
 Carol | White
```

how would you display the following:

```
Name   | Car Colour  |   Indiv. Car Index
------------------------------------------- 
 Alice | Red         |    1
 Alice | Green       |    2
 Alice | Blue        |    3
 Bill  | Orange      |    1  
 Bill  | Purple      |    2
 Carol | Brown       |    1
 Carol | Orange      |    2 
 Carol | Magenta     |    3
 Carol | Indigo      |    4 
 Carol | Lilac       |    5
 Carol | White       |    6
```

Edit - thanks for your speedy responses - they work in SQL Server 2008, but may I please ask what the alternative would be SQL Server 2000? - It doesn't seem to recognize ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: What version of SQL Sever do you use?

Comment: So, each `Name` gets a different numbering, but how do we use the `Colour` to know what index to assign. For `Alice`, it appears to be reverse alphabetical order, but for `Bill` is seems to be (forward) alphabetical and there's no pattern I can discern for `Carol`. Is there another column you've not shown us that is actually defining the order?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the index is not a function of the particular `Car Colour` - it just depends on the number of car colours each person has.

Comment: @ Hamlet Hakobyan please see post edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to order by default order for each `Name`, use `SELECT 0` in `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT Name, [Car Colour],
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) [Indiv. Car Index]
FROM YOURTABLE
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c6dc/1) to view result

**SQL SERVER 2000**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT (SELECT count(*) from #TEMP as e2
              WHERE e2.Name = e1.Name AND e2.[CAR COLOUR] <= e1.[CAR COLOUR]) as RNO, e1.Name,e1.[CAR COLOUR]
    FROM #TEMP as e1
)TAB
ORDER BY NAME,RNO
```

Answer (score 1):

To include the index number in `SELECT` query, use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT Name, [Car Color], 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY [Car Color] DESC) as [Indiv. Car Index]
FROM TableName
ORDER BY Name
```

Read more about `ROW_NUMBER()` [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35e48/8).

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty exhaustive - may I ask,what is the difference between Sarath Avanavu's ORDER BY (SELECT 0) and your ORDER BY CarColor?

Comment: @Bracket: Edited my answer. Updated the link. Feel free to accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: your update answer will only work if all cars have different colours and if you remove the order by which is invalid

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: I don't think so. This will work even if some cars have same colours. It is just ordering. Not grouping. Please refer [**this fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e64ec/1).

Comment: @RagingBull your fiddle is refering to the first part of your answer. I am refering to the UPDATE part of your answer. There are also some other issues with column names

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: Yup!! You are right!! Totally get it.. Removed that part from my answer. Thanks..

Comment: @RagingBull do you know what the analagous solution would be in SS2000?

Comment: @Bracket: Please refer [**this**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0f1f6d4d-ba40-4770-94b6-47657fe363db/sql-server-2000-alternate-to-rownumber) and [**this**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/13daeb85-da43-4166-b188-595a4a5d5282/simulate-rownumber-in-sql-2000).